# Use buttons (not radiobuttons) for Choicefield in Django?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have a Django form:

```
class Form0(forms.Form):
    # Do you agree to the terms?
    CHOICES = [ (1,'Yes'), (0, 'No')]
    response = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=CHOICES)
```

My views:

```
def home(request):
    '''
    entry
    '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.Form0(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            assesment, created = models.Assessment.objects.get_or_create(
                session_id=request.session.session_key,
                defaults={'data': {}})
            assesment.data.update({'Terms': form.cleaned_data['response']})
            assesment.save()
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            if form.cleaned_data['response'] == '1':
                return redirect(reverse("question1"))
            else:
                return redirect("conclusion")

            resp =  HttpResponse('ok')
            return resp
    else:
        form = forms.Form0()

    resp = render(request, 'coreapp/index.html', {'form': form})
    if not request.session.session_key:
        request.session.save()
    return resp
```

It is being rendered in my HTML template. I have made a script to enable submitting the form when clicking on a radio button which works perfectly:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ form.as_table }} {% csrf_token %}
  <script>
    $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function () {
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
  </script>
</form>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

## The problem

Is it possible to display the 'Yes' and 'No' radioselect as normal buttons? E.g. using bootstrap buttons like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Yes</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">No</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by creating a for loop in my template and adding styling to the new 'myradio' class:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.response %} 
      {% for radio in form.response %}
        <div class="myradio">
          {{ radio }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

  <script>
    $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function () {
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use bootstrap `Checkbox and Radio Buttons`:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function (e) {
  $(this).closest('form').submit()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> No
    </label>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />

  <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options2" id="optionA" autocomplete="off" checked> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options2" id="optionB" autocomplete="off"> No
    </label>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />

  <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options2" id="optionA" autocomplete="off"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options2" id="optionB" autocomplete="off"> No
    </label>
  </div>
</form>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks Hybrid. The problem I'm getting with the above is if I click on one of these buttons, the form is not submitted. Also I' not sure if I need toggling, I just need a normal button that submits straightaway if clicking on 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: @TomMac I edited my code to include the JS, as well as a third example to use just regular buttons. Let me know if this works!

Comment: Sorry, Hybrid - I'm getting the same problem with not submitting anything when clicking on the buttons. The buttons looks great through (especially the final 'normal' buttons example you've included)

Comment: @TomMac are you handling the form on your backend with a `post` view? If you are I'd need to see that to diagnose further

Comment: Oh yes, good idea. I've just updated the question with the views.py

Comment: Try adding `print` statements in every step of your view - that way you will be able to see at which point it fails (when you dont see "Checkpoint X" print to the console). You can let me know where it fails